# Angularjs: $filter in controller

Tags: angularjs

Having issues with getting this filter to work.

```
$scope.imgCollection.then(function (images) {
    $scope.images = images.thisGal_images;

    if ($scope.images[0].order == '0') {
        console.log('orgName');
        $scope.images = $filter('orderBy')($scope.images, 'orgName');
    } else {
        console.log('sort order');
        $scope.images = $filter('orderBy')($scope.images, 'sortOrder');
        console.log($scope.images);
    }
});
```

$scope.images returns a list of images from the database. On the initial upload, the sortOrder column is populated with '0' as they can be sorted via ui:sortable. So on the initial view I base the sort order on the file name. After the initial view the DB is written and the first image is given the sortOrder of 1 and increments from there.

This could be my misunderstanding of $filter, but `$scope.images = $filter('orderBy')($scope.images,'sortOrder');` is not ordering my $scope.images based on sortOrder.

Thanks

Comment: How is it ordering your images?  What exactly is happening and what do you want to happen?  Can you give a small example?

Comment: What is the type of `sortOrder`? string or int?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I created a demo for you and hopefully you can compare the code and figure out the issue.

I guess you might forget to inject `$filter` module. Please take a look a the demo.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-repeat="image in images">{{image}}</div>
    <button ng-click="order('0')">By orgName</button>
    <button ng-click="order('1')">By sortOrder</button>
</div>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function ctrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.images = [{
        orgName: 'B',
        sortOrder: 111
    }, {
        orgName: 'A',
        sortOrder: 12
    }, {
        orgName: 'D',
        sortOrder: 13
    }, {
        orgName: 'C',
        sortOrder: 14
    }];

    $scope.order = function (order) {
        if (order == '0') {
            $scope.images = $filter('orderBy')($scope.images, 'orgName');
        } else {
            $scope.images = $filter('orderBy')($scope.images, 'sortOrder');
        }
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/)**</kbd>

Comment: taking a closer look, it appears that when I sort by sortOrder, which is set to INT in DB. The images are ordered: 1,10,11,12,2,3,4,5,6 etc. So probably getting converted to json string in my PHP

Comment: @Bungdaddy Yep, then you need to convert it to int.

Comment: thanks, that was the key. Example helped me figure that one out

Comment: thanks for the JSFiddle, I was curious how does the orderBy filter work on a boolean column, so I extended it: http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/149/

Comment: How can i add  ascending/descending order ?

Comment: @mhd you would add a + or - at the beginning of the string. E.g. $filter('orderBy')($scope.images, '-orgName')