# Angularjs orderBy in ng-repeat is affecting index. How to remove the correct elements from array?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of values I'm displaying in a table. When I don't order them, my removal code works exactly as intended.  I would like to order the values in the ng-repeat to group the data by role name, but that makes my splice function remove the wrong value.  What is the correct way to remove my selected value?

Html that works:

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="oneUserRole in ui.userRoleResultsList track by $index">
    <tr>
      <td>{{oneUserRole.UserId}}</td>
      <td>{{oneUserRole.RoleName}}</td>
      <td>{{oneUserRole.Details}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="Delete" data-ng-click="ui.removeUserRole($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
```

Html that doesn't work (sorts as desired, but removal doesn't work due to issue with index):

```
<tbody data-ng-repeat="oneUserRole in ui.userRoleResultsList | orderBy: 'RoleName' track by $index">
    <tr>
      <td>{{oneUserRole.UserId}}</td>
      <td>{{oneUserRole.RoleName}}</td>
      <td>{{oneUserRole.Details}}</td>
      <td class="text-center">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="Delete" data-ng-click="ui.removeUserRole($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
      <td>
    </tr>
<tbody>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.ui.removeUserRole = function (index) {
   // remove row from array.
   $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList.splice(index, 1);
  // other code to remove selected item from db omitted here.
}
```

Comment: 1 - How about you pass the user in, instead of the index? Then find the index of the user in the list. 2 - You could order the list in your controller and `ng-repeat` over the ordered list (it would probably be more performant too, since the ordering isn't happening on each digest).

Comment: @FrankModica, I understand the theory. It's that I'm not sure how.

Comment: Check out this answer for an example of using the `orderBy` filter once in the controller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18540704/angularjs-filter-in-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up trying the suggestions of both Jelle and Frank Modica. Thanks to each of you for your quick responses. The most efficient way was to pre-filter the list coming from the controller, rather than change the html.

Here is my controller function that gets the data into the $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList:

```
    // ******************************************************************
    // Get the existing active User Roles 
    // ******************************************************************
    function LoadUserRoleResultsList() {
        var errorSummary = 'Error retrieving UserRoles list';
        $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList = [];
        $scope.promise =
            $http.get(appConfig.GetRootUrl() + '/AdminUserRoles/UserRoleList')
                .then(function onSuccess(response) {

                    var result = apiResponseParser.Parse(response);
                    if (result.isSuccessful && result.data !== null) {
                        // presort by rolename.
                        $scope.ui.ddlUserRoleTypes = result.data;
                        $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList = $filter('orderBy')($scope.ui.ddlUserRoleTypes, 'RoleName');
                    }
                    else {
                        ReportErrorMessage(errorSummary, result.message); 
                    }
                })
            .catch(function onError(response) {
                console.log(response, " = caught response Error");
                    ReportHttpError(errorSummary, response);
                });
    }
```

The magic is in the two lines after the // presort by rolename  comment.

Answer (score 1):

If u would change

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="Delete" data-ng-click="ui.removeUserRole($index)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`

to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" title="Delete" data-ng-click="ui.removeUserRole({oneUserRole.UserId)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

And then make it filter out on userId like so :

```
$scope.ui.removeUserRole = function (userId) {    
for(let i = $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList.length; i > 0; i--) {
    if(userId == $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList[i]) {
        $scope.ui.userRoleResultsList.splice(i, 1);  
        break;   
    }
}
```

}

It should work I think